# Is it legal to call shared_future::get() multiple times on the same instance in the same thread?

Tags: c++, boost, future

I can find neither direct confirmation nor refutation on the matter. All answers seem to address the "access from multiple threads" aspect, rather than repetitive access itself.

Does the standard define the behavior for `std::shared_future`? What about `boost::shared_future`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per cppreference in [`std::shared_future<T>::valid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/valid)

> Unlike std::future, std::shared_future's shared state is not invalidated when get() is called.

Which makes sense. If it wasn't the case then you couldn't have multiple threads be able to call `get`.  We can further back this up by looking at the standard. In [[futures.unique.future]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/futures.unique.future#15) they explicitly state `get` only works once with

> releases any shared state ([futures.state]).

while in [[futures.shared.future]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/futures.shared.future#18) it states no such thing so the state is still valid after `get` is called.

---

`boost::shared_future` has the same behavior.  Per [the reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.shared_future) `get` has no text stating it invalidates the shared state on a call to `get` so you can call it multiple times.

Comment: By the way, a curious observation on boost::futures. The link in the answer leads to docs on `boost::fibers::shared_future`, which (again!) seem to differ in behavior from [boost::shared_future](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.shared_future) (which is defined in 'boost::thread').

Comment: Ah, found! It is stated in the first example on shared_future: `use3( ftr.get() ); // second use is defined`

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK this is legal. `std::shared_future<T>::get()` [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/get):

> The behavior is undefined if `valid()` is `false` before the call to this
>   function.

Going to `std::shared_future<T>::valid()` [it says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/valid):

> Checks if the future refers to a shared state.
>
> ...
>
> Unlike `std::future`, **`std::shared_future`'s shared state is not
>   invalidated when `get()` is called**.

Which would make multiple `get()` calls from the same thread and on the same instance valid.